# SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand not returning the right result

Tags: c#, dataset, sqlcommand, sqldataadapter

I am just facing a problem with my code.

I want to select some data from a database using the SqlDataAdapter SelectCommand property.

My code looks like:

```
static SqlConnection sqlConnection;
static SqlDataAdapter daDBData = new SqlDataAdapter();
static SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
static DataSet dsDBData = new DataSet("DBData");
static DataTable tblDBData;
static DataRow drCurrent;

public static DataTable dbDataGet(string tabname, string where)
{
    sqlConnection = dbConnect();    //sqlConnection setup working fine, defined in another method
    string helper = "SELECT * FROM " + tabname + where; 
    command = new SqlCommand(helper, sqlConnection);
    daDBData.SelectCommand = command;

    daDBData.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    daDBData.Fill(dsDBData, tabname);

    tblDBData = dsDBData.Tables[tabname];
    return tblDBData;
}
```

My problem is, that in `tblDBData` all existing rows of my database table will be returned.
What I miss here?

Comment: What is being passed as the `where` parameter value? Maybe if it's blank, you're just selecting ALL data from your table?

Comment: Can you dump the entire value of `helper` here?

Comment: Try adding spaces : "SELECT * FROM " + " " + tabname + " " + where;  Does the where contain the word WHERE : "SELECT * FROM " + " " + tabname + "  WHERE " + where;

Comment: On top of the problem you're asking about, I'm deeply concerned about the static nature of this code. This is absolutely not thread-safe. If you're using this in a web application, for example, connections will be leaked and left undisposed. Enabling MARS will prevent outright errors about open readers on the connection but you could easily overload a connection with too many results sets. It's best to use ADO.NET plainly. Classes like this are a bad idea.

Comment: @JonE
helper string content: SELECT * FROM products WHERE DATEDIFF(day, sale_date, GetDate()) >= 365 AND available=1

Answer (score 0):

As far as blocks of code go, it's probably fair to say that that one needs a lot of work. Nearly every line has something that could use some improvement but the whole concept that it embodies is fairly objectionable because it is inherently a massive security risk. Here's a minorly improved version:

```
//Don't need any of those static variables. Stop making everything static..
//In a properly structured C# program almost NOTHING should be declared as static

        //Method names in C# use PascalCase convention, not camelCase
        public DataTable DbDataGet(string tableName, string whereClause)
        {

            //this could be a massive security risk if there is any way at all that the 
            //user can influence the contents of the whereClause. DON'T DO IT if they can
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(
              $"SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE {whereClause}",
              GetConnectionString() //in this simplistic context, get a string, not a SqlConnection, then you don't handle disposal
            );

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);

            return dt;
        }
```

Yep; all that code you wrote boils down to just 4 lines. It's still a massive problem that you're just tossing a string with a where clause around. The only way you could get away from that with this approach is to start breaking your where string into a set of predicate classes, sql injection protected at the column and operator level, and adding the values to a SqlParameterCollection - it's essentially rolling your own data access library and isn't worth the bother given that many tens of people have already done it (including microsoft)

Consider instead getting away from this awful rabbithole by NOT doing your data access this way at all. Toss it all in the trash and use [Dapper](http://dapper-tutorial.net) instead. It's not a huge learning curve from where you are now, and will do everything in a safer, more secure and easier to use fashion

---

As a note on the WHERE clause you're saying in the comments that you're using:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, sale_date, GetDate()) >= 365 AND available=1
```

Don't do this either. Here you carry out a function operation on an entry of data in the table. If your table has a million dates in, that function will need to be called a million times. It's slow as heck, uses a huge amount of resources and cripples the use of indexes. And it's completely unnecessary. You're looking for all products sold more than a year ago? Calculate ONE DATE of what date it was a year ago and use the `SALE_DATE` from th tale without any alteration in comparison to it:

```
-- in your sql
WHERE sale_date < @someDate and available = 1

//in your c#
mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@someDate", DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-1));
```

See the difference? Here the c# calculates the date once, and provides it as a constant value parameter to the query. In a table of a million dates, only one simple compare is performed. We dont' caluclate how many days ago a million different dates were and then select only those diffs > 365